# Home-made impedance meter: what's the difference between voltage divider and active filter methods

Tags: impedance, meter

I'm dealing with the measurement of impedance sweeping the frequency from 0,1Hz to 100KHz. On the web I found many methods but the most quoted seems to be the one which uses an operation amplifier in inverting low-pass filter configuration:

[image]

Z represent the impedance under test. In this configuration, we can find the module and phase of Z comparing the input and the output of the filter.

Another simplest method I found is the common voltage divider:

[image]

Z is the impedance under test again and its module and phase can be found again comparing the input and the output signals.

Now, I know that the first method which uses the opamp should be the better choice since it's used in the most Z-meter, but I don't understand the real advantage using that one.

Can anyone light up my mind?

Comment: Z is measured under frequency, the filter allows to reduce some noise, so your filter must be on the frequency of usage of device under test (DUT). An LCR can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the op-amp when used as an inverting amplifier has a virtual earth at -Vin, the component "Z" is driven by "IN" with respect to ground. This means that the output of the op-amp (barring it being non-ideal and also ignoring the feedback capacitor) is representative of the current passing through "Z".

So you have two voltages; the drving voltage and a second voltage proportional to Z's current.

Therefore the op-amp route is simpler to compute impedance than having a voltage applied across Z in series with Ro and a voltage across Ro that is proportional to current through the series combination of Z and Ro.

Having said all of that and given the non-idealities of op-amps as frequency gets high, the 2nd approach will, inevitably, be more accurate if a little more complex mathematically to solve.

Comment: So are you tell me that the voltage divider is not so good of this kind of application because the expression of output voltage show a ratio where the numerator and denominator are not independent due to the presence of Ro in both? I think to got it. But when you say "as frequency gets high, the 2nd approach will be more accurate if a little more complex mathematically to solve", how should I get the frequency point where the non-idealities of opamp start to be  important? It's the opamp's bandwidth the limit or the input capacitance?

Comment: And last, why are you saying that the divider "will be more accurate if a little more complex mathematically to solve"? I think that it's not really complex to solve (maybe are different point o view).

Comment: "a *little* more complex" is true. If you don't regard the slight complexities as a big deal that is fine. For the op-amp, if you look at its open loop gain you'll see that beyond a certain frequency it no longer has gain therefore you have problems. There is also the input capacitance of the op-amp to consider and, when measuring capacitance, that the output voltage may becomes clamped to the power rails at high frequencies.

Comment: Ok I got it. Input capacitances apart, the frequency features of an opamp have significantly changes beyond several MHz, so for my application (0.1 - 100K Hz) the use of an active filter should be quite useful. Thanks.

Comment: @thoraz good luck with it. I think I'd go the op-amp route if Fmax is 100 kHz.